# Dovecot not starting

Tags: server, email, mail, dovecot

I've been trying to tackle this for a while now and I'm completely stumped. I believe I have all of my settings correct, however, when I try to run `/etc/init.d/dovecot start` command I get this message:

> sudo: /etc/init.d/dovecot: command not found

If I run `sudo service dovecot start` I get:

dovecot start/running, process 1646

However, when I run `netstat -natp` I don't see the service, or the port listening, and there is no dovecot log file in /var/log/.

To be thoughrough I also ran `grep "starting up" /var/log/*` and there is no dovecot result

Also, I'm using exim4 rather than postfix for my SMTP services.

Any help here would be great.

Comment: How did you install Dovecot? What's the result of `ll /etc/init.d/dovecot`, `systemctl list-units "dovecot*"` and `find /usr -name dovecot`?

Comment: I installed using `sudo apt-get install dovecot`. 

The output of `ll /etc/init.d/dovecot` is "ls: **cannot access /etc/init.d/dovecot: No such file or directory"**

The output of `systemctl list-units "dovecot*"` is **systemctl: command not found**

And the output of `find /usr -name dovecot` is:
**/usr/sbin/dovecot
/usr/share/doc/dovecot-core/dovecot
/usr/share/dovecot
/usr/lib/dovecot**

Comment: Sorry, my install command was actually `sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd`

Comment: So it looks like Dovecot is properly installed through the package manager. If there's no `systemctl` -- what version of Ubuntu are you running? Still on 14.04, which uses Upstart instead of systemd? 14.04 did not ship an init file at all, but has Dovecot managed by upstart instead. I won't be able to help you with running Dovecot with upstart, don't have any Ubuntu 14.04 machine left.

Comment: Yea it's an old machine that I repurposed, so Ubuntu 14.04 was the latest OS I could get working on it. Completely understandable, and I thank you for the help you did provide.